# Choosing microservice using AWS EC2 and ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am trying to develop a spring cloud micro services. And I planned to deploy into AWS cloud. When I reading AWS resources I found that ECS providing configuration less environment for deploying microservices other than EC2. My doubt is that

1. Can I choose ECS resource for my complete services deployment without configurations?
2. For creating ECS service, is EC2 instance mandatory? Can I use ECS only in my account without creating EC2 VM? I need to know about ECS is alternative for EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECS is a service which offers clustering of vm for docker container, manages container lifecycle.

1) Yes. You can use ECS for your service deployment and it needs some basic configuration which will be one time.

2) No. To run docker container you need EC2 instance without that its not possible to run. EC2 instance are managed by ECS so you only need to provide some config like region,security group etc.

For complete config and deployment refer below link.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_GetStarted.html

Comment: Regarding the second question, AWS recently launched Fargate, which doesn't need you to create EC2 instances anymore: https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/